# Select second match regex using ruby

Tags: ruby, redmine

How can I get a second mail address from below strings.
My function get only first email.
Does somebody know, how to get a second group using ruby?

```
tmm = "F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl: XY pawel.brodo@buziaczek.pl"
tmm2 = "F91EBC8A89CACD48824377A0AA020847501DEF@exchange.wp.pl: XY pain@test.pl"
tmm3 = "F91EBC8A89CACD4882437D37AA020847501E27@exchange.wp.pl: XY test245wielki@testo.pl"

 wynx = tmm.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+)/i)
 $LOG.error ":::::::::::#{wynx[0]}" //F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl
 $LOG.error "+++++++++++#{wynx[1]}" //F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl
```

Comment: I don't have a Ruby interpreter handy to try this as I'm at work, but try tmm.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+)/i)[2]. Should return the second match.

Comment: `str.split.last` works with the strings you provided: `"F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl: XY pawel.brodo@buziaczek.pl".split.last` => `"pawel.brodo@buziaczek.pl"`

Comment: The regex match returns the same string in both elements

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#scan`

```
tmm = "F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl: XY pawel.brodo@buziaczek.pl"

wynx = tmm.scan(/[\.a-zA-Z0-9]+@[\.A-Za-z0-9]+/i)
wynx[1]
#=> "pawel.brodo@buziaczek.pl"
```

Comment: What? The first one is `F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl` and second one is `pawel.brodo@buziaczek.pl`. `wynx` is array of these two addresses!

Comment: "brodo@buziaczek.pl" != pawel.brodo@buziaczek.pl

Comment: Change the regex to `/[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+/i` and it will work. Notice the dot added in the first character class (as was done in the second character class). The rest is the same.

Comment: Hmm, my mistake. @Anthony. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$LOG = Logger.new('/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/log/production.log')
tmm = "F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl: XY pawel.brodo@buziaczek.pl"

wynx = tmm.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+)/i)
$LOG.error ":::::::#{wynx}CCC"
$LOG.error ":::::::#{wynx[0]}"
$LOG.error ":::::::#{wynx[1]}"
```

and i got a following answer :

```
:::::::F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl
:::::::F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl
:::::::F91EBC8A89CACD4882737A0AA020847501DD6@exchange.wp.pl
```